# How to embed SQL in iOS app?

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite

I want to embed some sql statements into my objective-c ios app.  can i use `SELECT` and these statements or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tutorials how to integrate SQLite in your iPhone app:

- [iPhone Programming Tutorial – Creating a ToDo List Using SQLite Part 1](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)
- [iPhone SDK Tutorial: Reading data from a SQLite Database](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite` is `sqlite`, in iOS or... not :)

And sqlite has, of course, [SELECT](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

If you intend using `sqlite` with iOS, you should give a look at [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Giving a look at CoreData is also a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

yes.

- [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)
- [iPhone SDK Tutorial: Reading data
  from a SQLite Database](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)
- [12 SQLite
  Resources for iPhone Developers](http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good library to use for SQLite: https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder

It will help you write your SQL statements and has a powerful ORM.  If you prefer to use straight raw SQL, you can just use its database connection class.